# slope for linear models with different intercepts: how to standardize/normalize slopes to compare?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have code to fit linear models to data in R. My independent variable is AGE and my dependent variable is Costs. I am interest whether Costs in general increase with AGE in years. However for some parts my intercept is 10 whereas for others my intercept is 1000 and thus an increase in currency units is not helpful, since a slope of 1 unit per year might be a lot for an intercept of 10 and a slope of 1 currency unit per year is neglectable. Could anybody help with how to solve this issue, to standardize slopes in R to compare them after calculating them with `lm`?

**Example**

```
data.ex <- data.frame(Age = c(c(1:10), c(1:10)),
                  Costs = c(11,12,13,14,15,12,17,18,19,20, 1001,1002,1003,1004,999,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010),
                  Type = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)))
pt <- ggplot(data = data.ex, aes(x=Age, y = Costs))+
geom_smooth(method="lm")+
facet_wrap(facets = "Type", nrow = 2)
plot(pt)
print(with(data.ex[data.ex$Type == "A", ], lm(Costs ~ Age)))
print(with(data.ex[data.ex$Type == "B", ], lm(Costs ~ Age)))
```

Comment: Add `scales = "free_y"` argument to `facet_wrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others, setting `scales = 'free'` in `facet_wrap` will make both lines more visible in the plot.

To your other question, your wording is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you're saying, "If baseline costs start at $10, then an increase of $1/year is substantial, whereas at a baseline cost of $1,000, $1/year isn't significant. How do I show that difference?"

One way would be to normalize each group against its intercept:

```
library(dplyr)

# calculate intercepts for each group and extract them:
intercept.ex <- group_by(data.ex, Type) %>% 
  do(data.frame(intercept = coef(lm(Costs ~ Age, data = .))[1]))

# normalize the values in each group against their intercepts
data.ex <- merge(data.ex, intercept.ex) %>% 
  mutate(Costs = Costs / intercept)

# Age slope = 0.1002
print(with(data.ex[data.ex$Type == "A", ], lm(Costs ~ Age)))

# Age slope = 0.001037
print(with(data.ex[data.ex$Type == "B", ], lm(Costs ~ Age)))
```

I should point out that both slopes are still *statistically significant*, since the relationship between Age and Costs is quite clear. But the *relative effect size* is very different between them.

Comment: I learned a lot from your code, also about dplyr, one of my favourite packages. Thank you!!

Do you have an idea why my question was downvoted? I am a little confused, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Oh, and could you maybe outline what is the advantage of using the "do" call? thanks :)

Comment: The phrasing of your question was a little unclear, which is why you got a down vote. As for `do`, this function is meant to work together with `group_by`, applying a function or set of commands to each group created by `group_by`.

Comment: thanks for explaining. next time I will try to be more precise. your solution by normalizing on the intercept was great, thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a different scale of the y-axis...but in fact i really dont understand your problem.

```
Age = c(1:10)
Costs = c(11,12,13,14,15,12,17,18,19,20) 
plot(Age, Costs, type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)

Costs = c(1001,1002,1003,1004,999,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010)
plot(Age, Costs, type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
```